# Gradle leaves java as a process even after closing android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

On mac system whenever i close android studio it leaves java process and java process keep running and keep hogging the ram memory.Having a mac with only 4gb is sometime painful if you see that java process is taking upto 1gb of ram
[image]

[image]

is there any option in android studio so that as soon as i quit all the process related to it should be closed or any command that i can run for cleanup?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#N11731):

> Daemon processes will automatically terminate themselves after 3 hours of inactivity. If you wish to stop a Daemon process before this, you can either kill the process via your operating system or run the gradle --stop command. The --stop switch causes Gradle to request that all running Daemon processes, of the same Gradle version used to run the command, terminate themselves.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I want to ask that is there any setting in gradle or in JVM to automatically stop before 3 hours?

Comment: it's a shame that we're half way through 2019, and this hasn't changed in 4 years or so many iterations of the Android Studio IDE. :(

Comment: Still, a problem even in 2022 when ram consumption has increased tremendously.

Comment: Even after 3+ hours when my mac sleep, it didn't finish the process right away

Answer (score 4):

No option in Android Studio AFAIK. One way to cleanup would be create a shell script that launches Android Studio and then kills off any leftover java processes afterwards e.g.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
studio.sh
pkill -f gradle-launcher
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because Android Studio uses gradle daemon by default (see [here](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/ECrb9VQW9XP)) and as far as I know it can't be turned off. Have a look [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-daemon-never-stop-after-closing-ide/10628/2) also - gradle daemon should time out after 3 hours.