# Why does OpenJDK Platform Binary stucks open and use too much ram?

Tags: java, flutter

I started learning flutter recently and i noticed even if vscode closed OpenJDK Platform Binary stays open and uses too much ram. Should i force close it on task manager everytime i finished working on vscode? Is there any way to automatically close it? [image]

Comment: Do you use Gradle? It might be the Gradle daemon running in the background.

Comment: The project that i created with vscode "flutter new aplication project" has a gradle file in it but i don't really know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a documented behaviour of gradle. You can see this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300184/gradle-leaves-java-as-a-process-even-after-closing-android-studio/32300657#32300657) and this [closed issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63945) in the flutter github project.

> Daemon processes will automatically terminate themselves after 3 hours
> of inactivity. If you wish to stop a Daemon process before this, **you
> can either kill the process via your operating system or run the
> `gradle --stop` command**. The `--stop` switch causes Gradle to request that
> all running Daemon processes, of the same Gradle version used to run
> the command, terminate themselves.

You can disable it permanently by following [these steps](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:ways_to_disable_gradle_daemon) :

> The Gradle Daemon is enabled by default, and we recommend always
> enabling it. You can disable the long-lived Gradle daemon via the
> `--no-daemon` command-line option, or by adding `org.gradle.daemon=false` to your `gradle.properties` file. You can find details of other ways to
> disable (and enable) the Daemon in Daemon FAQ further down.

You can find an explanation [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:why_the_daemon) about why the daemon is important for performance  :

> Why the Gradle Daemon is important for performance
>
> The Daemon is a long-lived process, so not only are we able to avoid
> the cost of JVM startup for every build, but we are able to cache
> information about project structure, files, tasks, and more in memory.
>
> The reasoning is simple: improve build speed by reusing computations
> from previous builds. However, the benefits are dramatic: we typically
> measure build times reduced by 15-75% on subsequent builds. We
> recommend profiling your build by using --profile to get a sense of
> how much impact the Gradle Daemon can have for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so is there any harm of force close in task manager?

Comment: You're welcome. No there is no harm in closing it via the task manager. In the official docs, using the task manager is one of the methods to close it . You can also do a `gradle --stop` command to stop it. The daemon is used to avoid the cost of the jvm startup time when a gradle command is executed. You can disabled permanently by following these [steps](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#daemon_faq).

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have been of help

Comment: they use 2-4 gigabytes of RAM, they load disk up to 100% and they say that it's going to be like this up to 3 hours?

Answer (score -1):

- **Solution 1**

If your mobile hotspot is on in your PC then turn it off. And restart your PC. I think your problem will be solved.

*If it does not work then follow the below code ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓*

- **Solution 2**

**Step 1: Run the SFC.**

1. Click on the Start button, and Type CMD.
2. Right-click on CMD and select Run as Administrator.
3. Type “***sfc /scannow***” without quotes and hit Enter.
4. After the scan, restart the computer.

Now check for the issue.

**Step 2: Run the DISM Tool.**

1. Click on the Start button, and Type CMD.
2. Right-click on CMD and select Run as Administrator.
3. In the Administrator: Command Prompt window, type the following commands. Press the Enter key after each command:

   a) ***DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth***

   b) ***DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth***
4. To close the Administrator: Command Prompt window, type Exit, and then press Enter.

*Restart your PC. Your problem will be fixed*

Also, you can follow this reference [Link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/openjdk-platfrom-binary-almost-taking-up-90-memory/b86fc2de-7975-4b48-a2a9-4e5ebaec547a)